# efficient way of string search in a file

Tags: python

I had 2 files 'example' and 'inp' as follows:

contents of file example:

```
hi      wert    123

jui     fgrt    345

blabla  dfr     233
```

contents of file inp:

```
jui
hi
```

I need to fetch the first column of each line of 'example', and if that string exists in file 'inp', then i want to write that entire line of 'example' to another file out.txt
This is the code that i had written:

```
f=file('example')
f1=file('inp')

for l in f.readlines():
    s=l.split()
    for p in f1.readlines():
            if s[0] in p:
                    print l >> 'out.txt'
```

I am not able to get the expected result. And also, since the file example literally has 200000 entries and i think this sort of program takes too much time. Is there any method by which i can complete my task correctly and fast. Help much appreciated. Thank You

Comment: sorry...in the file inp, jui and hi words are in different lines, not space seperated

Comment: use `f.xreadlines()` or `iter(f)` or `for line in f` if you want to save memory

Comment: Your variable names are both descriptive and informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('inp') as inp: inp_words = set(line.strip() for line in inp)

with open('example') as example, open('result', 'w') as result:
    for line in example:
        if line.split()[0] in inp_words:
            result.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this? It first loads inp file and then it iterates over example file, printing only the lines that start with a word contained in the list of words read from inp.

```
with open('inp') as inpf:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in inpf]

with open('example') as exf, open('out.txt', 'w') as outf:
    for l in exf:
        if l.split(' ', 1)[0] in lines:
            print >>outf, l
```

You can also use a `set` to make search faster. Searching in a set has O(1) average cost. Just change the first `with` statement with this:

```
with open('inp') as inpf:
    lines = set([l.strip() for l in inpf])
```

And if you are using Python 3, then use `print` function instead of the "old" statement:

```
print(l, file=outf)
```

Comment: @jterrace I was just adding that :)

Answer (score 1):

If "inp" is a reasonable size, I would read all it's strings into a set, then iterate through the lines of "example"

(untested psudo-ish code)

```
words = set()
for line in inp:
  words.add(line)

for line in example:
  if line[0:line.find(' ')] in words:
    print line
```

The in-memory set lookup is super fast, you only read each file once.

Comment: Python has a built-in `set` type, there is no need to hack it.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of optimization:

1. Use set for faster search
2. Split the lines from example just until the first space character
3. No additional new lines in the output file unlike when using print >> or print()

.

```
with open("inp") as f:
    a = set(l.rstrip() for l in f)

with open("out.txt", "w") as o, open("example") as f:
    for l in f:
        if l.split(" ", 1)[0] in a:
            o.write(l)
```

Comment: That should just be "for l in f"

Comment: @spatar: you may have taken your variable name length optimization a little too far ;-)

Comment: @HughBothwell: Yeah, in a bigger code snippet I would use self-explanatory names. I hope this one was easy to read :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating through each *line* in the file. Try:

```
s=l.split()
for line in f1.readlines():
    for p in line:
        if s[0] in p:
            print p, 'matches', s[0]
```

If you want to do this super fast, compile a regular expression for the search string, and try to find it in the entire string representation of the file.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
with open('inp') as inf:
    words = inf.read()

with open('example') as inf, open('out.txt', 'w') as outf:
     for line in inf:
         word = line.split()[0]
         if word in words:
             outf.write(line)
```

yields:

```
hi wert 123
jui fgrt 345
jui hi
```

Comment: thank you. but this code works for smaller files. i have nearly 200000 entries in the file example. I need a faster way to achieve my result. If i follow this code, it takes (Total no. of lines in example x Total no. of lines in imp) amount of time(thats a lot slower). Can you have efficient method of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

You can sort the inp file and then try a binary search!